# How to generate a file with a new file name each time its run in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, auto-generate, pandas.excelwriter

I have code that generates an xlsm file everytime I run it.
What I want to do is that each time I execute that code it will look at the directory and see if the file `Top5NS_Report.xlsm` is there: if it sees that it generates a new file as such `Top5NS_Report(1).xlsm`. Similarly, if I run it again it should generate `Top5NS_Report(2).xlsm`.
I'd also appreciate if someone could further guide me about how to schedule my jupyter notebook to run daily at a specific time and generate these files in ascending order.

Here is the bit of code to generate a file:

```
writer=pd.ExcelWriter( 'Top5NS_Report.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
bigdata.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

workbook = writer.book
workbook.filename = 'Top5NS_Report.xlsm'
workbook.add_vba_project('./vbaProject.bin')
```

Comment: Look into `os.path.isfile` and run a loop until you find one that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Why not appending date/hour information ? It would also solve the sorting issue.

```
import datetime

filename = "Top5NS_Report_%s.xlsm" % (datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M'))
print(filename)
```

About scheduling, you could convert your notebook into a .py file an run it from a cron job.